# libGDX create an atlas out of a folder of images

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am following a tutorial at [Game from Scratch](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/10/02/LibGDX-Tutorial-3-Basic-graphics.aspx)

I am confused at the following:

`java -cp gdx.jar;extensions/gdx-tools/gdx-tools.jar com.badlogic.gdx.tools.imagepacker.TexturePacker2 c:\tmp c:\tmp spritesheet 
tmp`

I have a required folder with images how do I convert it into an atlas?

This question might sound feeble, I am just a beginner. Any help would be great :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the GUI version of texturepacker, its quite simple to use.

https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-texturepacker-gui/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Maybe you need to split it on some separated atlas

Comment: Okay, let me try with a subset of 100 images! I am doing this for the sake of learning so does not matter!

Answer (score 3):

Place all images you want to be in final atlas in one folder and its subfolders. Create `pack.json` file with configuration in the folder and each subfolder (optional step). Run following code (save it into `MyPacker.java` file) :

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.tools.texturepacker.TexturePacker;
public class MyPacker {
   public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
       TexturePacker.process(inputDir, outputDir, packFileName);
 }
}
```

It may take a some time (seconds or even minutes) to finish. The process may result in more than one texture atlases. Please note that not only picture altas will be created but also a `*.atlas` file describing content of the atlas.

Created atlas can be used as source of textures following way:
extureAtlas atlas;

```
TextureAtlas atlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("packedimages/pack.atlas"));
AtlasRegion region = atlas.findRegion("imagename");
Sprite sprite = atlas.createSprite("otherimagename");
```

Please read the current [documentation](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Texture-packer) to see other options and details about `pack.json` configuration files.

Comment: I am not able to import tools, I am using the gradle based setup on ANdroid

Comment: You should add the gdx-tools dependency to gardle configuration files. look here: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Dependency-management-with-Gradle

Comment: Thanks bro, I figured that out but ended up using the GUI tool instead.

Comment: GUI is good, but it don't have the power of automation. Consider for example rebuilding of atlas automatically when any of input images change.

Comment: please can you add how to access all regions of a subfolder ?